# Converting Mac OS X's Picture Clipping Files to Image Files

Tags: macos, finder, image-conversion

My wife has extracted a bunch of images from a larger document by individually selecting the images and then dragging them to a folder on her Desktop.  These now show up as "picture clipping" files in the Finder.

She now needs these in JPEG format.  We know that we can do this by opening each file in the Finder, selecting Copy, going to the Preview app, selecting the New from Clipboard menu item, then selecting Save As.

However, there are 150 of these images, so she would rather not go through these manual steps for each clipping file, nor would she like to re-extract them from the original document.

So, is there any way to automatically "mass convert" these clippings to JPEG or another useful file format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned ImageMagick is ideal. The other thing is to use Automator.app to convert. It comes with the Mac and some people find it less intimidating than the command line, presumably the point of having it built-in.

Create a new "Application" in Automator and add the "Change Type of Images" workflow action.  Set it to convert to JPEG, then save the application somewhere.

When you drag an image onto the application, it will convert it to a JPEG for you.  If you don't want to delete the original photo, then add the "Copy Finder Items" action to the top of your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for ImageMagick. You will need to [install it](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx) and learn a little about using the terminal. But it's a great tool to have handy for batch image processing. Open Terminal, navigate to the image folder (e.g. "`cd Desktop/Images`") and run:

```
mogrify -format jpg *
```

Comment: You can also try GraphicsMagick rather than ImageMagick. Fewer dependencies. http://www.graphicsmagick.org/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an oooold question, but there's a less-involved way for the those of us who'd rather not use the Terminal.

• Open a blank TextEdit document (your computer comes with this program)
• Select all the Untitled Clipping™s and drag them into the TextEdit window
• Save it somewhere, like the Desktop, as a .rtfd
• Right-click this RTFD file and go to Show Package Contents
• Tada! There're all your images.

Answer (score 0):

I would take all these files and put them on the desktop. Then,click and drag until all the files are highlighted. Lastly, go to finder and click "copy" and enter the preveiw app and selecting the New from Clipboard menu item, then selecting Save As. Each file will be saved with a new, unique name.